# What happens when you pass an object to an ActiveJob enqueue and that object no longer exists at perform time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activejob

If one were to create an ActiveJob and the perform block accepts an argument that is expected to be a single instance of an ActiveRecord object, then when the job is enqueued the object in question exists, but at the actual perform time that object no longer exists, the job would obviously fail, right?

```
MyJob < ActiveJob::Base
  def perform(widget)
    # do some stuff to widget
  end
end
```

So once this job that fails because ActiveJob can't instantiate the original ActiveRecord object, it's going to keep failing. What update could be made to the job to stop the failure loop. I considered hooking to `before_perform`, but I haven't seen a path forward yet.

Outside of solving the issue at hand, the other thing I've learned here is that it would have been better to pass a `widget_id` integer rather than the ActiveRecord object. Then I would have been able to check and see if the widget in question still exists from inside the perform block.

Comment: Mentioned here : https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/19793

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can [`rescue_from`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html#exceptions) the `ActiveJob::DeserializationError` that gets thrown when an object can no longer be found. Note: this deserialization happens before the perform callbacks kick in which is why you can use the perform callbacks to handle the situation.

So, in your job class you can add:

```
class MyJob < ActiveJob::Base

  rescue_from(ActiveJob::DeserializationError) do |exception|
    # return true (we rescued) if the error causing the deserialization
    # error was a record not being found
    exception.original_exception == ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
  end
end
```

If `rescue_from` returns `true` then it indicates that the error has been handled and that the job completed successfully. In this case I've just checked if the error that caused the deserialization error was an `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` (which is what the [`globalid` gem](https://github.com/rails/globalid) that ActiveJob uses to serialize and deserialize ActiveRecord objects causes when it cannot find the object).